# How to configure port forwarding with nftables for a Minecraft server on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: networking, routing, port-forwarding, nat, nftables

Since I'm using a transparent proxy service, I use a raspberry pi as my home router. Its OS is plain Raspbian. Now I'm setting up a Minecraft server on `192.168.2.28`, and am exposing it to WAN using NAT. Here's my `/etc/nftables.conf`:

```
#!/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table ip filter {
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        tcp sport 25565 drop
    }
}

table ip nat {
    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority 0; policy accept;
        tcp dport 25565 dnat 192.168.2.28
    }

    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 0; policy accept;
        tcp sport 25565 ip saddr 192.168.2.28 masquerade
    }
}
```

However, I have the following issue:
On `192.168.2.28`, I run
`nc -l -p 25565`
On `192.168.2.27`, I run
`echo "Hello, world!" | nc wan_ip 25565`

The wanted behavior is that I get the "Hello, world!" message on `192.168.2.28`.

However, when the first SYN packet goes through the router, it only has its daddr NATed, keeping its saddr equal to `192.168.2.27`.

When `192.168.2.28` receives the packet, it replies to `192.168.2.27`. Since they are in the same L2 network, the packet doesn't go through the router, hence not NATed.

Then `192.168.2.27` receives the packet from `192.168.2.28`, but it doesn't know this is the reply from `wan_ip`.

How can I fix this issue and make port forwarding work everywhere, including from LAN hosts?

Comment: This issue is a well known issue with a name for handling it: [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_hairpinning).

Comment: Actually it's not a NAT hairpinning problem (because the current ruleset should have been doing NAT hairpinning by itself). Looks like a typo.

Comment: @A.B What typo is it?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a typo or a comprehension problem. I'm opting for a comprehension problem so I also explained briefly how Netfilter handles NAT.

Comment: I modified my answer were some explanations were slightly inaccurate even if the commands were adequate, and added a 4th bullet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a reminder, *nftables* (just like *iptables*) sees only the first packet of a flow to be NAT-ed. When it comes to doing NAT, every other packet in the same flow will be handled directly by *Netfilter*/*conntrack* without seeing *nftables* anymore: so the return traffic is automatically un-NAT-ed without further assistance.

The only part that matters is what happens to the very first packet (so for TCP it's a SYN packet). Further traffic for this flow, including reply packets is automatically handled and bypasses NAT hooks.

That means there should be no special postrouting rule to handle traffic emitted from 192.168.2.28. There should be only a generic rule to masquerade *all* of 192.168.2.0/24 when communicating towards Internet. Anyway this rule is not a problem in itself: it just won't be used as often as one think when the emitted traffic is reply traffic: it's part of a pre-existing flow, so as written above, such packets won't traverse *nftables* anymore.

What is important is to have proper [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_hairpinning) support: the case where the client is in the same LAN as the server and asymmetric traffic would happen without proper care.

Here:

- when the router sees anything (coming from anywhere) destined to tcp destination port 25565, redirect the destination address to 192.168.2.28

  As the redirection doesn't discriminate from outside and from inside, this rule should have been enough on its own when associated with an adequate generic masquerade rule for the whole LAN. But OP didn't use such rule.
- Instead of generic masquerade in postrouting,

  OP used `tcp sport 25565 ip saddr 192.168.2.28` which has no relation to the previous rule's filter part for the same *first* packet `tcp dport 25565` (and which has also received new *destination* 192.168.2.28): NAT hairpinning is not achieved.

What *should be done* instead is either one of:

1. use a generic masquerading for the whole LAN (adapted to NAT hairpinning use case and lack of additional information)

   ```
       chain postrouting {
           type nat hook postrouting priority 0; policy accept;
           ip saddr 192.168.2.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.2.0/24 masquerade
       }
   ```
2. use masquerading only when the server is the destination, for packets with a destination rather source port 25565

   ```
       chain postrouting {
           type nat hook postrouting priority 0; policy accept;
           tcp dport 25565 ip daddr 192.168.2.28 masquerade
       }
   ```

   That means only traffic to the server, including LAN-to-LAN for proper NAT hairpinning is masqueraded (LAN systems won't be able to reach Internet).
3. Instead of 2. choose to apply masquerade only to traffic that first got DNAT

   ```
       chain postrouting {
           type nat hook postrouting priority 0; policy accept;
           ct status dnat masquerade
       }
   ```

   Same effect as 2. but more generic.
4. combine 1 and 3 to masquerade only when needed

   Bullets 2. or 3. have the side effect of hiding the Internet source address, so better apply that only for the LAN:

   ```
       chain postrouting {
           type nat hook postrouting priority 0; policy accept;
           ip saddr 192.168.2.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.2.0/24 ct status dnat masquerade
       }
   ```

So either use 1. or 4. (to restrict LAN access to Internet) There are other choices possible.

Note: There's a corner case for 1. : if the client uses the router's internal IP address as target it won't work without an additional rule for this case, but I doubt the client will do this, and I don't have enough information from OP: the router's internal IP address.