# nft port forwarding not working on router

Tags: networking, routing, port-forwarding, nat, nftables

I have a machine that serves both as a router and a server. I have several lxc containers on this machine, and want to expose them to both the LAN and WAN. Following https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-configuring_port_forwarding_using_nftables I was able to successfully access the servers from both WAN and LAN machines, but not localhost/the router-server itself!

Here is the configuration that partially works:

```
# Created from lxc-net in debian
table inet lxc {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
                iifname "lxcbr0" udp dport { 53, 67 } accept
                iifname "lxcbr0" tcp dport { 53, 67 } accept
        }

        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                iifname "lxcbr0" accept
                oifname "lxcbr0" accept
        }
}
# Created from lxc-net in debian
table ip lxc {
        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                ip saddr 10.0.3.0/24 ip daddr != 10.0.3.0/24 counter packets 51 bytes 3745 masquerade
        }
}

# This is what I added
table ip myportforwarding {
        chain prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
                tcp dport 8088 dnat to 10.0.3.230
        }

        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                ip daddr 10.0.3.230 masquerade
        }
}
```

I tried several options from this answer: [How to configure port forwarding with nftables for a Minecraft server on Raspberry Pi?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/745869/how-to-configure-port-forwarding-with-nftables-for-a-minecraft-server-on-raspber)

Nothing seemed to work to enable local access to the services on 8088.

Looking at wireshark, access from LAN looks like:

```
192.168.1.105 -> 192.168.1.1 SYN
10.0.3.1 -> 10.0.3.230 SYN
...
```

Access from the same machine:

```
192.168.1.1 -> 192.168.1.1 SYN
192.168.1.1 <- 192.168.1.1 FIN!
```

I'm not too familar with nft or iptables, so I'm sure there is something I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at a  part of the *Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking* schematic. It was made for *iptables* but most of it applies for *nftables*:

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]

It's documented that the *nat* table is consulted only for packets in conntrack state NEW: packets starting a *new* flow.

Routed/forwarded traffic arrives from the *nat/prerouting* hook: that's where new flows will have a chance to be NAT-ed. OP handled this case.

Locally initiated packets (created at the *local process* bubble in the center) first traverse the *nat/output* hook, then their answer will come back as usual through the *nat/prerouting* hook. Leaving aside the fact that the destination is already not changed for the query, as the answer matches the flow that was created before, it's not a packet in NEW state anymore: the *nat/prerouting* hook will never be consulted for such traffic because it's too late: the only place to do NAT was *nat/output*.

So for this case where both routed and locally initiated packets should receive the same alteration, rules in *nat/prerouting* have to be duplicated in *nat/output* and usually slightly adapted to match the different case.

The adaptation here is about the host reaching itself, so for the routing case where the interface is the loopback (`lo`) interface, thus adding `oif lo` to it.  Without this filter, any query from the host to anywhere using port 8088 would be redirected to the container, while only the case for the host to itself is intended.

Adding this chain in the already existing *ip myportforwarding* table will handle it:

```
        chain output {
                type nat hook output priority dstnat; policy accept;
                tcp dport 8088 oif "lo" dnat to 10.0.3.230
        }
```

For the little details: a change from *nat/output* triggers the *reroute check* part, where the routing stack is told to reconsider the previous routing decision (output interface `lo`). After *reroute check* the output interface becomes `lxcbr0`.

Comment: Note: I'm not sure the postrouting chain should exist at all (it prevents the server to identify the clients by IP address), but this is beyond what's asked, and anyway it would be needed if the system uses localhost instead of $HOST to reach itself.

Comment: This works! (Though I had to use -100 instead of dstnat as a priority) postrouting is required for services in the lxc network to access themselves using the public IP. I include it in this question because it is a part of getting port forwarding working, hence why I included the minecraft server question link. Is there a way to keep the ip address in that scenario? None of the other minecraft server question answers worked for me

Comment: To avoid NAT except for LXC's NAT hairpinning: `nft flush chain ip myportforwarding postrouting`; `nft add rule ip myportforwarding postrouting 'ip saddr 10.0.3.0/24 ip daddr 10.0.3.230 masquerade'`. Should the host also need to use 127.0.0.1 in addition to 192.168.1.1, use instead `nft add rule ip myportforwarding postrouting 'ip saddr { 10.0.3.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8 } ip daddr 10.0.3.230 masquerade'` and in addition (that's what matters, for re-routing to work): `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.lxcbr0.route_localnet=1`.